# C++ Linux - Change Timezone to a certain timezone

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to synchronize my server time with client time, I got the code to fetch the server time, which is below. If I run it in server, upon client login. I will send time to the client, but how do I change the "client" system time to the time I send from the server.

I googled about setenv and such, but how do we actually change the time in Linux C++?

Using the code below, I can get the current time:

```
/* localtime example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changing time would require root access. Why dont ypu synchronize your time using NTP (http://www.brennan.id.au/09-Network_Time_Protocol.html).

Comment: I think it's distro-dependant, for example in Gentoo you edit /etc/timezone, symlink /etc/localtime or set the TZ environment variable.

Comment: `settimeofday` but I think you want to get the system to do that for you and not have to worry about it.

Comment: You've got things mixed up. You mention setting timeZONE, but than you are getting TIME in the code bit. So which do you want?

Answer (score 3):

A Linux (or Unix, or Posix) system measures the time from the [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). No timezone is really involved at the lowest level (the time related [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), and the kernel). Timezone are a library thing, thru [localtime(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/localtime.3.html) and [strftime(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strftime.3.html) and other functions.

Read also the [time(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) man page.

You really want to synchronize time (on both local and remote machines) using the [NTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) (use `ntpd`, `chrony`, `ntpdate` ....), or at least `rdate` (but NTP is preferable).

The system calls to query the time are [gettimeofday(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html), [time(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/time.2.html), [clock_gettime(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with `CLOCK_REALTIME`

You might use [settimeofday(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/settimeofday.2.html) and [adjtimex(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html) syscalls to set the time. This usually requires root privilege.